# Does Effective Level Stack with Actual Level?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, multi-classing, character-levels

I am building a level 7 Exemplar Brawler/level 2 Dirge Bard. Exemplar gets [Inspiring Prowess](https://pfsrd.site/Advanced%20Class%20Guide/Rules/Class%20Options/Brawler/Exemplar/Inspiring%20Prowess), which is effectively inspire courage with its effective Bard level equal to Brawler level -2.

Since I have actual levels of bard, do these stack for an effective bard level of 7 for this ability, or is it just considered a separate pool and I have two different sources of bardic inspiration to keep track of?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### No

The Bard levels do not stack and you have to keep track of both abilities/pools separately.

[Inspiring Prowess](https://www.aonprd.com/ArchetypeDisplay.aspx?FixedName=Brawler%20Exemplar) does not say that it stacks with Bard levels:

> **Inspiring Prowess (Ex):** At 3rd level, an exemplar gains the ability to
> use certain bardic performances. She can use this ability for a number
> of rounds per day equal to 3 + her Charisma modifier; this increases
> by 1 round per brawler level thereafter. The exemplar’s effective bard
> level for this ability is equal to her brawler level – 2. At 3rd
> level, the exemplar can use inspire courage. At 11th level, the
> exemplar can use inspire greatness. At 15th level, the exemplar can
> use inspire heroics. Instead of the Perform skill, she activates this
> ability with impressive flourishes and displays of martial talent
> (this uses visual components). This ability otherwise functions as
> bardic performance; feats and other effects that affect bardic
> performance (such as the Extra Performance feat) apply to it. This
> ability replaces maneuver training and AC bonus.

But in order to stack, abilities need to specifically call out that they stack, as per [this FAQ](https://paizo.com/paizo/faq/v5748nruor1fm#v5748eaic9o80):

> ***Channel Energy: If I have this ability from more than one class, do they stack?***
>
> No — unless an ability specifically says it stacks with
> similar abilities (such as an assassin's sneak attack), or adds in
> some way based on the character's total class levels (such as improved
> uncanny dodge), the abilities don't stack and you have to use them
> separately. Therefore, cleric channeling doesn't stack with paladin
> channeling, necromancer channeling, oracle of life channeling, and so
> on.

Comment: If I GM'd this, I'd let you stack it. But alas, RAW isn't as nice.

Answer (score 0):

No.

Unless it is explicitly stated in the definition, abilities from different classes do not stack at all.

For example, if you are a wizard that gets cleric levels at some point, you cannot combine the spell slots of both classes into one pool - wizard spells go into the wizard spell slots, and cleric spells go into the cleric spell slots. The one exception to this is if you are a Mystic Theurge 10, which gets a special ability that lets you do exactly that, but using slots in this way requires using a slot a level above its normal level (for example, if you can cast *fireball* as a wizard and want to use cleric slots for it, you would need to use a level 4 slot).